# How to raise an exception in a try-except-else statement

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

I have a decision-making function that if the length of input is less than 2, an error is raised and it moves to the next input; if the length of input >= 2, no error and this input is executed. However, I have **issues adding raise-exception into this try-except-else**.

A very simplified version is like this:

```
x = 3
try:
    assert (x < 2)
    print("only one class")
except:
    assert(x > 1)
    print("processing this quad")
else:
    print("moving to next quad")
# output is "processing this quad"

x = 1
try:
    assert(x < 2)
    print("only one class")
except:
    assert(x > 1)
    print("processing this quad")
else:
    print("moving to next quad")
# output is "only one class
moving to next quad"
```

Ideally, my raise exception would work the same way. That if input < 2, it raises an exception and move to the next. If >=2, it processes this input. However, it **seems exception-raising is not compatible with Else**, that I get the error below. (the input is length of a list called unique_cc. here, unique_cc = 1). **I want it to raise an exception then print "move to the next". Anyone help me with that?**

```
    try:
        assert(len(unique_cc) < 2)
        raise Exception("Data has only 1 non-zero class - rejected for random forest.")
    except:
        assert(len(unique_cc) > 1)
        print("processing this quad")
    else:
        print("moving to next quad")
```

[image]

Comment: Well, yes - that's the *entire point* of raising an Exception: to break up the local control flow and let the next exception handler decide what should happen next. The *entire point* of the `else` block on `try/except/else` is to contain code that *only happens* when the `try` block *does not* raise an exception. I can't understand how you want this to work, or what problem you hope to solve by making it work that way.

Comment: " an error is raised and it moves to the next input" doesn't make sense, therefore. If you want to *display* an error, then you can just use e.g. `print`. But the entire point of *raising* is to declare that *it is not logically possible* to just "move to the next input". Exceptions are for problems that you can't handle locally.

Comment: Use if statments. try-except blocks aren't meant to be used for common logic gates.

Comment: You probably don't want to use *assert* for runtime logic. Optimised Python runtime (i.e., when started with the -O option) disables assertions

Comment: Hi @KarlKnechtel, I specifically want an error because I need to record the error in a database - and then the database does something - another irrelevant story.

Comment: So... directly call the "record an error in the database" code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Python assert keyword with error message

```
while True: 
    unique_cc = 0
    try:
        unique_cc = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        #break
    except ValueError:
        print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")

    assert unique_cc < 2, "Data has only 1 non-zero class - rejected for random forest."
        # raise  Exception("Data has only 1 non-zero class - rejected for random forest.")
    assert unique_cc > 1, "processing this quad"
    break
print("moving to next quad")
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a meeting after posting the questions and realized the only and best way to do it is having outer&inner functions. This is exactly the method I switched to.

Comment: you're welcome and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    assert x >= 2
    print("processing this quad")
except:
    print("only one quad")
    print("moving to next quad")
```

If you only want it to print "moving to next quad" if the values of x is less than 2, this should do what you want. If the assert statement fails, it immediately jumps to the except clause.

I should point out that normally a simple if else statement would handle this just fine rather than an assertion that throws an exception. Unless you want this to behave more like a unit test that throws, say, a custom Failure exception

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply **raise** error and move on. You need to **ignore/handle/log** error and move on. By the way, in most cases you don't need else clause with try clause. it makes no difference if you put that in the end of try clause in most cases.

**Also be sure to use logging.exception only in except clause.** Otherwise it may result in unexpected weird behavior.

example of doing "log error and carry on":

```
import logging
for i in range(5):
    try:
        assert(1 == i)
        print("try", i)
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("error")
    else:
        assert(1 == 1)
        print("else", i)
    finally:
        print("finally", i, "\n")
print("end")
```

output:

```
ERROR:root:error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
AssertionError
finally 0 

try 1
else 1
finally 1 

ERROR:root:error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
AssertionError
finally 2 

ERROR:root:error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
AssertionError
finally 3 

ERROR:root:error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
AssertionError
finally 4 

end
```

You can save that logging error results in separate file as well for cleaner output